# Como dar unset em um coockie ao fechar o navegador

Tags: php, cookies

Em PHP estou criando um coockie de login assim:

```
$data = "e".gmdate("dmY");
setcookie("elogado", $data, time() + 600, "/");
```

Quando fecho o navegador e reabro, se vou verificar o coockie assim:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["elogado"])){
    echo "sim";
}
```

Ele cai dentro desse if, ou seja, o coockie não some ao fechar o navegador. Existe alguma forma de dar unset ao fechar o navegador e/ou aba?

Comment: O sentido do cookie é ele se manter até quando se fecha o navegador. use o $_SESSION para isso que ele será removido ao fechar o navegador

Comment: Se você não definir o tempo de vida (duração) de um cookie, ele irá durar o tempo que o browser permanecer aberto.  setcookie('elogado', $data);

Comment: @Sveen ótimo, funcionou!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo testei isso, mas não rolou...

Comment: Veja no manual na parte `expire` http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php que diz `Se configurado para 0, ou omitido, o cookie irá expirar ao fim da sessao (quando o navegador fechar).` Entenda que fechar o navegador é fechar todas as paginas independente de pertencer ou não ao site.

Comment: @Sveen, tanto `$_SESSION` quanto `cookie sem data de expiração` vão funcionar até que se feche o navegador. Inclusive no seu comentário você afirma isso. O que talvez o AP não sabe é o que significa `fechar o navegador` nesses casos. Talvez pense que é fechar a/as paginas do site que criaram a session ou cookie quando na verdade deve fechar todas as paginas abertas do referido navegador.